# Mongodb: How can i check if a count is smaller than a value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I have an assignment for school in which I have to retrieve a list of students which have x amount of failed tests.

A student has a schema like this one
[student scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iOY5.png)

A failed test is when a student has less than 10 on a course.

The amount here is the amount of fails that is given by the frontend (count of fails has to be more than this amount)

This is what I have but obviously it is not working. I just don't know how to check if the count of the amount of failed tests is bigger than 'amount'

```
 let amount = 1
    let students = await Student.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$studentNr',
                count: {"$sum": amount}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                count: {
                    'courses.score':{$lt: 10}
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

thanks in advance

**ANSWER**

Thanks to Buzz Moschetti I was able to find the correct answer.

```
    let amount = parseInt(req.body.amount);
    let students = await Student.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                name: "$name",
                studentNr: "$studentNr",
                courses: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$courses",
                        as: "course",
                        cond: {$lt: ["$$course.score", 10]}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {$match: {$expr: {$gt: [{$size:'$courses'}, amount]}}}
    ]);
```

Comment: You can try your aggregations out if you download the mongo Compass, then you can easily see what is happening and where your aggregations fail.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, your schema has all courses+scores for each student in an array.  So what you need to do is not `$group` (because each doc as a unique student id) but rather `$filter` on the `courses` array and keep only those with `score` less than 10.  After that, you would `$match` on the `$size` of the filtered array equal to `amount`.   Since this is homework, I'll leave it there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm now able to get all reviews with a score lower than 10 but I've been having trouble finding the $match. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've updated my question with what I have now.

Comment: Hint:  You need to use `$expr` in the `$match` to get the `$size` of the array.

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much sir. You have been so helpful. I would like to upvote your comment but I don't have enough reputation. Lol.
I'm selecting your answer as the correct one.